# Writing a helper function for a binary search tree copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

First of all my tree is made up of nodes that look like this:

```
struct Node 
{ 
    string name;
    Node *left; //points to the left child        
    Node *right; //points to the right child    
};
```

For my copy constructor I have a helper function which passes in the root, I call it like this (in my copy constructor):

```
 root = Helper(base.root);
```

Now for the body of copyHelper I need a little help with the copying of the actual string for each node.

```
    Node* newNode = new Node; 
    string newName = new string; 
    newName = other->name;
    newNode->name = newName;

    newNode->left = Helper(other->left); 
    newNode->right = Helper(other->right);
```

Do I need to include anything else in Helper, and why am I getting that error when creating a string on the heap?

The error on the string line is:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string *' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
```

Comment: Why doesnt the string need a new?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states, an attempt is being made to assign a `string*` to a `string`. To correct the error:

```
string newName;
```

There is no requirement to create the `string` object on the heap. Also, there appears to be no reason to have `newName` at all:

```
Node* newNode = new Node; 
if (newNode)
{
    newNode->name  = other->name;
    newNode->left  = Helper(other->left); 
    newNode->right = Helper(other->right);
}
```